# Mixed textures in blender shifted off, any idea how to solve it?

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, node-editor, image

So, I've been texturing this model for days now, following a tutorial but after mixing the textures to get the ideal skin tune, I did a quick render and the textures are shifted off, they are far from the place they should be and the colors are not strong either.
[image]

His mouth is near his right eye and nose while his eyes are on the right side of his head. The problem is, and the reason why I have absolutely no idea, how to correct this mistake is, if I check the textures one by one, then it shows up correctly like this:
[image]

Anyone can help me? I am desperate at this moment :(
By the way, I was using this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vAwpRyES21I

Comment: Did you do UV unwrap?

Comment: Yes, I did, but the problem is still there :/

Comment: Could you show the texture's **Mapping** panel? (https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/textures/mapping/introduction.html)

Comment: Of course. Here: http://s29.postimg.org/6gh640j4m/forquestion.jpg

Comment: And the panel above (Image Mapping)? Is Repeat set to 1-1? If you want, consider the option to upload your blendfile (or a part of it) for a deeper inspection http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/